# assigning an element to an empty array

Tags: java, arrays

How do I assign the same elements from two arrays to another empty array in Java?
I can't figure out how to select the same elements from two arrays and assign them to another empty array. I don't know how to do without using **ArrayList.**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        findDuplicate();
    }
    public static void findDuplicate() {
        try {
            int[] array1 = {12, 15, 6, 3, 9, 8, 1, 3, 99};
            int[] array2 = new int[]{1, 5, 3, 3, 8, 99};
            int[] sameElements = {};
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
                    if (array1[i] == array2[j]) {
                        count++;
                        for (int k = 0; k < count; k++) {
                            sameElements[k] = array1[i];
                            System.out.println("sameElements[k] = " + sameElements[k]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the text of the code. Never post the screenshot of the code.

Comment: Read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) to see why you need to cut and paste the code rather than linking a picture. I was going to help with your question, but I can't be bothered to retype all your code. When you're asking strangers to help you for free, you need to make it easy for them to do so. You also need to explain what your code is trying to do and what you think isn't working. Your current explanation is vague to the point of meaninglessness.

Comment: use array list instead ArrayList<Integer> myNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    myNumbers.add(array1[j]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        findDuplicate();
    }

    public static void findDuplicate() {
        int[] array1 = { 12, 15, 6, 3, 9, 8, 1, 3, 99 };
        int[] array2 = { 1, 5, 3, 3, 8, 99 };

        // Array of the smaller length (out of the lengths of array1 and array2)
        int[] sameElements = new int[array1.length < array2.length ? array1.length : array2.length];

        int i, j, k, count = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
                if (array1[i] == array2[j]) {
                    // If 0 is present in both, array1[] and array2[]
                    if (array1[i] == 0) {
                        count++;
                        continue;
                    }

                    // Search if array1[i] exists in sameElements[]
                    for (k = 0; k < count; k++) {
                        if (sameElements[k] == array1[i]) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    // If array1[i] is not already in sameElements[], put it into sameElements[]
                    if (k == count) {
                        sameElements[count++] = array1[i];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.print("Duplicates: ");
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            System.out.print(sameElements[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Duplicates: 3 8 1 99
```